# Why is my update statement not working in SQL Server Management Studio against my Azure Database?

Tags: sql, azure, ssms

I have written a very basic update statement that was working fine previously and now, for reasons unknown, no longer updates any data, despite not returning any errors.

I have two tables, NewCars and OldCars

**New Cars**

```
CarId  INT      [NONE NULLABLE]
Make   VARCHAR  [NULLABLE]
Model  VARCHAR  [NULLABLE]
Design INT      [NULLABLE]
OldId  INT      [NONE NULLABLE]
```

**Old Cars**

```
CarId    INT     [NONE NULLABLE]
Make     VARCHAR [NULLABLE]
Model    VARCHAR [NULLABLE]
DesignId INT     [NULLABLE]
```

I need to copy the 'Design' from the old table to the new one.  Here is the query that I wrote that has worked with previous columns in this database.

```
UPDATE NewCars
SET Design = (SELECT DesignId FROM OldCars WHERE OldCars.CarId = NewCars.OldId)
```

When I run my statement, it completes with the message 'x Number of rows affected' x being the total record count.  When I check the data, the column has nothing in it.  I tried this same approach on other columns and it does the same thing.

I have tried restarting my Azure database which didn't change anything.  I then tried to run a query to check if another query statement was perhaps still running, there seems to be nothing there.  I've made sure the source and destination data types are the same as well.

Can anyone help me with what has gone wrong here?

Comment: `CarId.OldId` is wrong. Would the query even run with that?

Comment: I've corrected that, I simply copied it out incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to accopmplish with this update but this will work:

```
update NewCars
set Design = (select DesignId from OldCars  WHERE OldCars.CarId = NewCars.CarId);
```

In your update statement you have `NewCar.OldId` and `NewCars` table does not have a `OldId` column(from your specifications). And also it is NewCars with s in the end. So please check the statement and give us the one with no errors and no updates...

If you want to update column `NewCars.Design` with a value from column `OldCars.DesignId` where the column `NewCars.CarId`  matches column `OldCars.OldId` then the value in the column `OldId` can not appear more than one time. Else, you will have an error.

Comment: I did a check but the OldId is unique and doesn't appear more than once.  The query completes, it's just that nothing happens.

Comment: Hi @Yanayaya which query did you run ? Please can you run this: `update NewCars
set Design = (select DesignId from OldCars WHERE OldCars.OldId = New_Cars.CarId);`

Comment: I ran the following query which includes my corrections.

'update NewCars
set Design = (select DesignId from OldCars  WHERE OldCars.CarId = NewCars.OldId);'

The reports that all rows are affected despite nothing being changed.

Comment: Hi @Yanayaya i see some updates...Ok, I see, the column is moved to NewCars...

Comment: Hi @Yanayaya I will have to ask you one thing more: please can you tell me one ID from the table NewCars that you expect to update with this ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to VBoka for assiting with this, it turns out there were problems with the corrolation of the Id numbers as the column data was incorrect.

Comment: Hi @Yanayaya did this helped : "Hi Yanayaya I will have to ask you one thing more: please can you tell me one ID from the table NewCars that you expect to update with this ? Thanks!" If so I would appreciate to mark the answer as accepted and I will update the answer with the info from comment. Cheers. Happy you have founded your solution. Cheers!